# Each Turtle need to pick different agents from the same agentset

Tags: netlogo, heading, agentset

i got a problem with my breed (amministrazione spurgatori). 
I need each one of them to pick a different target from the same agentset (manholes with segnalato? = true) but they all head to the same patch. 
I think the problem is the code in "to direzione amministrazione" but i am not sure.
Any suggestions? 
Thank you in advance

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;; CARATTERISTICHE ;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

globals
[
  grid-x-inc                                                          ;;per definire la grandezza degli isolati (quadrati verd)
  grid-y-inc
  intersections
  manholesO                                                            ;; tombini sulle strade orizzontali
  manholesV                                                            ;; tombini sulle strade verticali
  roads
  valore-Scenario-degrado
]

turtles-own
[
ufficio
segnalati
work
house
goal
speed
applicazione?
]

breed [cittadini cittadino]
breed [amministrazione spurgatore]

patches-own
[
 intersection?                                                          ;;vero se è intersezione tra due strade                                                             ;;vero se è tombino
 ostruzione-da-rifiuti                                                      ;; da definire bene
 segnalato?
]


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;; PROCEDURA DI SETUP ;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  setup-globals
  setup-patches
  set-Scenario-Degrado
  let goal-candidates patches with [
    pcolor = 37 and any? neighbors with [ pcolor = white]
  ]


 create-cittadini n-of-cittadini
  [
    set size 1
    set color black
    set shape "car"
    set speed 0.07
    set house one-of goal-candidates                                     ;;crea la tartaruga casa
    set work one-of goal-candidates with [ self != [ house ] of myself]  ;;crea una localizzazione diversa per ogni tartaruga
    set goal work                                                        ;;crea direzione attuale
    move-to house
    set applicazione? false
     ]

  ask n-of NOALLATESSERADELTIFOSO cittadini [set applicazione? true]

  create-amministrazione n-of-spurgatori
  [
    set size 1
    set color red
    set shape "person"
    set speed speed
    set ufficio one-of goal-candidates

    set goal ufficio
    move-to ufficio
  ]

end

;;con setup globals si definiscono le dimensioni della griglia in questo caso non è modificabile

to setup-globals

  set grid-x-inc world-width / 7
  set grid-y-inc world-height / 7

end


;;con ask patches definisco le pacth che rappresentano i quadrati intorno alle strade con set road le strade

to setup-patches
 ask patches                                                            ;;caratteristiche generali delle patch verdi
  [ set intersection? false
    set pcolor 37
    ]
 set roads patches with                                                 ;;definisco quali sono le strade attraverso le coordinate
    [(floor((pxcor + max-pxcor - floor(grid-x-inc - 0))
        mod grid-x-inc) = 0) or
    (floor((pycor + max-pycor) mod grid-y-inc) = 0)]

  ask roads [ set pcolor white ]

  ;;vado a definire le intersezioni, capire bene
 set intersections roads with                                            ;; definisco quali sono le intersezioni attraverso le coordinate
   [(floor((pxcor + max-pxcor - floor(grid-x-inc - 0)) mod grid-x-inc) = 0) and
   (floor((pycor + max-pycor) mod grid-y-inc) = 0)]

 set manholesO roads with                                                 ;;definisco quali sono i tombini sulle strade orizzonatli
   [(floor((pxcor + max-pxcor - floor(grid-x-inc - 0)) mod grid-x-inc) = 4) and
   (floor((pycor + max-pycor) mod grid-y-inc) = 0 )]

 set manholesV roads with                                                 ;;definisco quali sono i tombini sulle strade verticali
  [(floor((pycor + max-pycor - floor(grid-y-inc - 0)) mod grid-y-inc) = 4) and
   (floor((pxcor + max-pxcor) mod grid-x-inc) = 0 )]


  setup-intersections
  setup-manholesO
  setup-manholesV


end

to setup-intersections
  ask intersections
  [
   set intersection? true
  ]
end

to setup-manholesO
  if setup-manholes? [
  ask manholesO
 [  set pcolor 109
    set segnalato? false
    set ostruzione-da-rifiuti 0
  ]
  ]
end

to setup-manholesV
  if setup-manholes? [
  ask manholesV
 [  set pcolor 109
    set segnalato? false
    set ostruzione-da-rifiuti 0
  ]
  ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;; PROCUDERA DI AVVIO ;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:

to go
tick
  network
  go-cittadini
  go-amministrazione
  ask manholesO [                                                          ;;il tempo di svuotamento aumento di 1 ogni tick
    ostruzioneO
  ]
  ask manholesV
  [
  ostruzioneV
  ]

  attappamento
end

to network
  if Metodo-diffusione-applicazione = "Passaparola"
[
    ask cittadini with [applicazione? = true]
    [if any? cittadini in-radius 1 with [applicazione? = false] and random-float 1.0 < Probabilità-connessione
      [create-link-with one-of other cittadini in-radius 1 with [ applicazione? = false ]
      ]
 ]
  ]



    end

to segnalazione
  ask cittadini with [applicazione? = true]
  [
 if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 2 = 103 [
      ask patch-ahead 2 [set segnalato? true]
    ]
  ]

    end


to go-cittadini

 ask cittadini
  [face next-patch                                                      ;;per andare verso la direzione quindi definisce il movimento (forse non serve up-car?)
    fd speed
    variation-speed
    direzione-cittadini
    segnalazione
    ask link-neighbors [ set applicazione? true ]
      ]
  ask cittadini  with [applicazione? =  true][ ask in-link-neighbors
  [ set applicazione? true]
  ]

end

to go-amministrazione
  ask amministrazione
  [
    face next-patch2
    fd 0.05
    direzione-amministrazione
  ]
end

to direzione-cittadini
  if goal = house and (member? patch-here [ neighbors4 ] of house) [ set goal work ]
  if goal = work and (member? patch-here [ neighbors4 ] of work) [ set goal house ]
end

to direzione-amministrazione

  set segnalati patches with [segnalato? = true]

  if not any? patches with [segnalato? =  true] [set goal ufficio]
  if any? patches with [segnalato? = true ] [set goal one-of segnalati]

  if count patches with [segnalato? = true] > 1 [
    set goal min-one-of (patches with [segnalato? = true]) [distance myself]
  ]

  spurgo

end

to spurgo

  ask amministrazione [
    if [segnalato?] of patch-here = true [
      set ostruzione-da-rifiuti 0
      set segnalato? false
  ]
  ]

end


to variation-speed
  if rain? [
  ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 2 = 103
  [set speed 0]
  [ifelse pcolor = 107
    [set speed 0.025]
    [set speed 0.05]
  ]
  ]


end

to ostruzioneO                                                              ;; il tombino cambia colore in base al livello di ostruzione
  if setup-manholes?  [
    ifelse ostruzione-da-rifiuti >= 600

      [ifelse ostruzione-da-rifiuti >= 1200
        [set pcolor 103]
        [set pcolor 107]
      ]
  [set pcolor 109]
  ]
end


to ostruzioneV                                                               ;; il tombino cambia colore in base al livello di ostruzione
if setup-manholes? [
  ifelse ostruzione-da-rifiuti >= 600

      [ifelse ostruzione-da-rifiuti >= 1200
        [set pcolor 103]
        [set pcolor 107]
      ]
  [set pcolor 109]
  ]
end


to attappamento
  ask cittadini [ if any? cittadini-on manholesO [set ostruzione-da-rifiuti ostruzione-da-rifiuti + valore-Scenario-degrado] ]
  ask cittadini [ if any? cittadini-on manholesV [set ostruzione-da-rifiuti ostruzione-da-rifiuti + valore-Scenario-degrado] ]

end

to set-Scenario-degrado
  if Scenario-degrado = "Basso" [
    set valore-Scenario-degrado random-float (2 - 0) + 0
  ]
  if Scenario-degrado = "Medio" [
    set valore-Scenario-degrado random (4 - 2) + 2
  ]
  if Scenario-degrado = "Alto" [
    set valore-Scenario-degrado random-float (6 - 4) + 4
  ]
end

to-report next-patch

  let choices neighbors with [ pcolor = white or pcolor = 109 or pcolor = 107 or pcolor = 103]                      ;;qui per farli passare sui tombini modificare con i colori che si impostano

  let choice min-one-of choices [ distance [goal] of myself ]                                                   ;;fai fare la distanza alla tartaruga
  report choice
end



 to-report next-patch2

  let choices neighbors with [ pcolor = white or pcolor = 109 or pcolor = 107 or pcolor = 103 ]                      ;;qui per farli passare sui tombini modificare con i colori che si impostano

  let choice min-one-of choices [ distance [goal] of myself ]                                                   ;;fai fare la distanza alla tartaruga
  report choice
end
```

Comment: I can't see anywhere in this code where you actually ask the agents to select a target. Please show just the relevant code: the procedure that is giving you the problem and perhaps the procedure that calls it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please edit your question rather than write an answer with your updates. Here is a cleaner version of your code.

```
to go-amministrazione
  ask amministrazione
  [ face next-patch2
    fd 0.05
    direzione-amministrazione
  ]
end

to direzione-amministrazione
  set segnalati patches with [segnalato?]
  if-else any? segnalati
   [ set goal one-of segnalati
     set goal min-one-of segnalati [distance myself]
   ]
   [ set goal ufficio ]
  spurgo
end
```

What I have done is:

1. replaced first `patches with [segnalato? = true]` with `patches with [segnalato?]` - you don't need the =true bit (and you can say `not` instead of =false too)
2. replaced all the other `patches with [segnalato? = true]` with segnalati (since you actually define this patch-set - once it's defined, you should just use the name so that NetLogo doesn't have to keep recreating the patch-set to count it
3. recognise that if there's only one segnalato then it's also the closest segnalato
4. combine the logic flow into a single `if-else` statement so NetLogo only has one truth test to assess rather than three

Looking at this code, you can obviously delete the line `set goal one-of segnalati` and have the same effect.

Having said all that, I can't see anything logically wrong with this code. Each amministrazione should be choosing the closest segnalato as its goal.

What I would do is create many more segnalato and then manually inspect several amministrazione that are near a segnalato to see whether it is choosing the correct one. It may be that you happened to create your segnalato in locations that are not near any amministrazione to so the amministrazione end up mostly choosing the same segnalato because it happens to be central.